# Unable to remove GIMP on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, gimp

I am trying to uninstall Gimp but unable to do so. It is also not allowing me to install any other packages as well.

Error on running "sudo apt-get remove gimp"

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp-gmic : Depends: gimp (>= 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
 sane : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It suggests to run the fix-broken command. I typed "sudo apt --fix-broken install" and came another error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2-common libgconf-2-4 libllvm6.0:i386 libllvm7 libllvm7:i386 libllvm8 libllvm8:i386 x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-gl-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgimp2.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgimp2.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 155 not upgraded.
106 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/773 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,971 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 272384 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgimp2.0_2.99.1+om~7-0ubu18.04.2~ppa_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgimp2.0 (2.99.1+om~7-0ubu18.04.2~ppa) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgimp2.0_2.99.1+om~7-0ubu18.04.2~ppa_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libgimp-3.0.so.0.9901.0', which is also in package libgimp3.0 2.99.1+om~19-0ubu18.04.4~ppa
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgimp2.0_2.99.1+om~7-0ubu18.04.2~ppa_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Other supporting gimp packages. I am not able to remove them also. "dpkg --list   | grep gimp"

```
ii  gimp                                                             2.99.1+om~19-0ubu18.04.4~ppa                    amd64        The GNU Image Manipulation Program
ii  gimp-data                                                        2.99.1+om~19-0ubu18.04.4~ppa                    all          Data files for GIMP
ii  gimp-gmic                                                        1:2.4.5+om-ubu18.04.1~gimp299~ppa               amd64        GIMP plugin for GREYC's Magic Image Converter
ii  libgimp3.0                                                       2.99.1+om~19-0ubu18.04.4~ppa                    amd64        Libraries for the GNU Image Manipulation Program
```

Additional details about gimp : "apt-cache show gimp"

```
Package: gimp
Priority: optional
Section: graphics
Installed-Size: 17693
Maintainer: Otto Meier <otto@kesselgulasch.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.99.1+om~19-0ubu18.04.4~ppa
Recommends: ghostscript
Replaces: gimp-plugin-registry
Suggests: gimp-help-en | gimp-help, gimp-data-extras, gvfs-backends, libasound2
Provides: gimp-helpbrowser, gimp-python
Depends: libgimp3.0 (>= 2.99.1+om~19-0ubu18.04.4~ppa), libgimp3.0 (<= 2.99.1+om~19-z), gimp-data (>= 2.99.1+om~19), gimp-data (<= 2.99.1+om~19-z), libgegl-0.4-0 (>> 1:0.4.15+om~0), libbabl-0.1-0 (>> 0.1.63+om~0), liblcms2-2 (>= 2.8), python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0), libmypaint (>= 1.4.0~7-ubu18.04.3~ppa~c196a86), mypaint-brushes (>= 1.0), gnome-icon-theme, libaa1 (>= 1.4p5), libappstream-glib8 (>= 0.6.7), libbz2-1.0, libc6 (>= 2.27), libcairo-gobject2 (>= 1.10.0), libcairo2 (>= 1.12.0), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.27.1), libgexiv2-2 (>= 0.10.3), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.55.2), libgs9 (>= 8.61.dfsg.1), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.5), libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 167), libharfbuzz0b (>= 0.6.0), libheif1 (>= 1.1.0), libilmbase12 (>= 2.2.0), libjpeg8 (>= 8c), liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614), libmng2 (>= 1.0.10), libopenexr22, libopenjp2-7 (>= 2.0.0), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.29.4), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.29.4), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.29.4), libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1), libpoppler-glib8 (>= 0.22.1), librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.19.1), libwebp6 (>= 0.5.1), libwebpdemux2 (>= 0.5.1), libwebpmux3 (>= 0.6.1-2), libwmf0.2-7 (>= 0.2.8.4), libx11-6, libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxext6, libxfixes3, libxmu6, libxpm4, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Breaks: gimp-plugin-registry
Filename: pool/main/g/gimp/gimp_2.99.1+om~19-0ubu18.04.4~ppa_amd64.deb
Size: 3978176
MD5sum: 1ed41694e65476e3f2f0e586e9485e8f
SHA1: 25e8a065af5a4a026b3f8519ce8da5cd9ec8e640
SHA256: 8fa5575b12bf3d2218bf88b85aa461018db98b036f7725f08e4ea6feb14804ca
Description-en: The GNU Image Manipulation Program
 GIMP is an advanced picture editor. You can use it to edit, enhance, and
 retouch photos and scans, create drawings, and make your own images.
 It has a large collection of professional-level editing tools and
 filters, similar to the ones you might find in Photoshop. Numerous
 fine-control settings and features like layers, paths, masks, and
 scripting give you total control over your images.
 Many image file formats are supported, including JPEG, Photoshop (.psd),
 and Paint Shop Pro (.psp) files. It can also be used to scan and print
 photos.
 .
 To open files remotely (like over HTTP), install the gvfs-backends
 package.
 .
 To use a MIDI device (like a musical keyboard) as an input controller in GIMP,
 install libasound2 and read the how-to at /usr/share/doc/gimp/README.MIDI
Description-md5: f2effb726861e0d75f53e1793347bcec
Original-Maintainer: Ari Pollak <ari@debian.org>

Package: gimp
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.8.22-1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/graphics
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers <pkg-gnome-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 15398
Provides: gimp-python
Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.8.22), libgimp2.0 (<= 2.8.22-z), gimp-data (>= 2.8.22), gimp-data (<= 2.8.22-z), python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.24.1), libaa1 (>= 1.4p5), libbabl-0.1-0 (>= 0.1.10), libbz2-1.0, libc6 (>= 2.15), libcairo2 (>= 1.10.2), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14), libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.88), libexif12 (>= 0.6.21-1~), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1), libgs9 (>= 8.61.dfsg.1), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.10), libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 167), libjpeg8 (>= 8c), liblcms2-2 (>= 2.2+git20110628), libmng2 (>= 1.0.10), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.29.4), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.29.4), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.29.4), libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1), libpoppler-glib8 (>= 0.18.0), librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4), libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3), libwmf0.2-7 (>= 0.2.8.4), libx11-6, libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxext6, libxfixes3, libxmu6, libxpm4, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), python2.7, python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
Recommends: ghostscript
Suggests: gimp-help-en | gimp-help, gimp-data-extras, gvfs-backends, libasound2
Filename: pool/universe/g/gimp/gimp_2.8.22-1_amd64.deb
Size: 3672180
MD5sum: ac5aee938db6979012c945b8f33613d7
SHA1: 9ccb7adb1d967d91cefe52bd99ce23eef76a95be
SHA256: 3cafbc52a67990691ec5102b56c760651d65e8057a3c4b522e1ca93877dfabd7
Homepage: https://www.gimp.org/
Description-en: GNU Image Manipulation Program
 GIMP is an advanced picture editor. You can use it to edit, enhance, and
 retouch photos and scans, create drawings, and make your own images.
 It has a large collection of professional-level editing tools and
 filters, similar to the ones you might find in Photoshop. Numerous
 fine-control settings and features like layers, paths, masks, and
 scripting give you total control over your images.
 .
 Many image file formats are supported, including JPEG, Photoshop (.psd),
 and Paint Shop Pro (.psp) files. It can also be used to scan and print
 photos.
 .
 To open files remotely (like over HTTP), install the gvfs-backends
 package.
 .
 To use a MIDI device (like a musical keyboard) as an input controller in GIMP,
 install libasound2 and read the how-to at /usr/share/doc/gimp/README.MIDI
Description-md5: 0c13253910a0a1bd77c64d38c07351a0
Task: ubuntustudio-publishing, ubuntustudio-photography, ubuntustudio-graphics
```

Comment: Did you install `gimp` from a ppa? Perhaps remove that ppa first.

Comment: @Jos Thanks I am able to uninstall Gimp after removing  PPA.